# Make use of AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining() / UsingFactoryMethod()

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle

I am registering many repositories which are located in the same assembly by using the following code:

```
IoCContainer.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<RepositoryOne>).BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<>)).WithService.AllInterfaces().Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Singleton));
```

Because I want to have influence on the creation of these repositories, I am trying to use UsingFactoryMethod() with it. Using this method is simple when I register every repository separately like

```
IoCContainer.Register(Component.For<IRepositoryOne>().ImplementedBy<RepositoryOne>().LifeStyle.Singleton.UsingFactoryMethod(() => Factory.New<RepositoryOne>()));
...
IoCContainer.Register(Component.For<IRepositoryN>().ImplementedBy<RepositoryN>().LifeStyle.Singleton.UsingFactoryMethod(() => Factory.New<RepositoryN>()));
```

But how can I use UsingFactoryMethod() together with the code from the first example?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a bit of reflection to use it, since you don't have the exact type of the object you'd be resolving.

```
var factoryMethod = typeof(Factory).GetMethod("New", BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public);

container.Register(
   AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<RepositoryOne>)
      .BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<>))
      .WithService.AllInterfaces()
      .Configure(x => x.UsingFactoryMethod((k, c) => factoryMethod.MakeGenericMethod(c.RequestedType).Invoke(null, null)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems that this functionality is only available in the version from Git (otherwise c.RequestedType is undefined), which throws a security exception when initializing here. Anyway, when a new version get's released, I will try it again.